# Hash.from_xml without ActiveSupport?

Tags: ruby

Anyone know a convenient way to translate XML to a hash, without an ActiveSupport dependency? ActiveSupport does have Hash.from_xml, but avoiding ActiveSupport?

Answer (score 0):

The [`gyoku`](https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku) gem might be helpful if you don't want to require the entire Active Support library.

```
Gyoku.xml(:find_user => { :id => 123, "v1:Key" => "api" })
```

There's also the [`to_xml`](https://rubygems.org/gems/to_xml/versions/0.1.1) gem, that extends the `Hash` object with the `#to_xml` method. A quick note: this `to_xml` gem doesn't seem compatible with Ruby on Rails.

Also, if you don't want to add any gems, you could define the serialization by yourself:

```
module Xml
  extend self

  def serialize(object)
    object.map do |key, value|
      noderize(key, value)
    end
  end

  def noderize(key, value)
    if value.class == Hash
      node_value = serialize(value).join
    else
      node_value = value.nil? ? "" : value
    end

    "<#{key}>#{node_value}</#{key}>"
  end
end

puts Xml.serialize({
  name: "Vinicius",
  username: "vnbrs",
  address: {
    country: {
      name: "Brazil",
      dial_code: 55
    },
    street: "R Jose Ananias Mauad",
    street_number: nil,
  }
})
```

And that outputs:

```
<name>Vinicius</name>
<username>vnbrs</username>
<address>
    <country>
        <name>Brazil</name>
        <dial_code>55</dial_code>
    </country>
    <street>R Jose Ananias Mauad</street>
    <street_number></street_number>
</address>
```

Comment: gyoku and to_xml both seem to go the wrong way.  I want XML to hash, not hash to XML. ActiveSupport Hash.from_xml is XML to Hash. Know of any similarly smallish gems that go that way?